# Video Streaming using UDP

Tags: java, udp, datagram

My question is how to use UDP to send data from webcam (Client-Server). I already implemented an Audio transfer application using UDP and it's working, but I have no idea how to get the data bytes from my webcam. For audio transfer I used the targetdataline and put the data in a temporary buffer and send it to the server. How can I use the same principle for video transfer. Below is how I get images from my webcam. Can anyone guide me what I can do next. Thank you.

```
    /* Grab the default web cam*/
    MediaLocator ml = new MediaLocator("vfw://0");

    /* Create my data source */
    DataSource ds = Manager.createDataSource(ml);

    requestFormatResolution(ds);


    /* Create & start my player */
    Player p = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(ds);

    p.start();
```

Comment: What language would you want a possible solution in?

Comment: I am using Java to implement my application.

Comment: My question is how to get the data bytes so that I can process it and send it using UDP (Datagram).